# Getting all Wifi-Connections and their details in tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking

I want to get all the Wifi Connections details in my iPhone App and connected my iPhone with any of Wifi Connection same as shown in the given picture[image]

can anyone guide me with any good tutorial Thankx in advance

Answer (score 1):

though you can get the list using the stumbler source code http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/ but this is undocumented API and if you wish to submit your app to the app store then it will get rejected , but will be ok with enterprise applications..